# Real-time Chat Issue with LARASOCKET and Livewire: Event Not Reloading Content

Tags: laravel, laravel-livewire

I'm using LARASOCKET and Livewire to implement real-time chat. However, I am encountering an issue where when a chat event occurs, it does not reload the chat content. I tried checking the event (MessageEvent.php), and it does say 'Broadcasting on chat channel.' But it does not run the 'log()' function.

**Livewire chat.php**

```
#[On('echo:chat,MessageEvent')]
    public function log($data){
        dd('hi');
    }

    public function send()
    {
        $this->validate();
        if (count($this->tags) === 1 || isset($this->selectConversations)) {
            if (isset($this->selectConversations)) {

                $id = $this->selectConversations; // id users
            } else {
                $id = $this->tags[0]['friendId']; // id users
            }
            $conversations = Conversations_UsersModel::where('user_id', auth()->user()->user_id)
                ->whereIn('conversations_id', function ($query) {
                    $query->select('conversations_id')
                        ->from('conversations_users')
                        ->where('user_id', $this->user_id);
                })
                ->get();
            if ($conversations->count() > 0 && isset($conversations)) {
                $conversationsId = $conversations->first()->conversations_id;
                $send = Conversations_MessagesModel::create([
                    'type' => 'text',
                    'source' => NULL,
                    'time' => now(),
                    'conversations_id' => $conversationsId,
                    'message' => $this->text,
                    'user_id' => Auth::user()->user_id,
                ]);
                if ($send) {
                    broadcast(new MessageEvent(Auth::user()->user_id,$send))->toOthers();
                    $this->text = '';
                    $this->getConversations();
                }

            }
        }
    }
```

**Event MessageEvent.php**

```
<?php

namespace App\Events\Clients\Conversations;

use App\Models\Conversations_MessagesModel;
use App\Models\UsersModel;
use Illuminate\Broadcasting\Channel;
use Illuminate\Broadcasting\InteractsWithSockets;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Broadcasting\ShouldBroadcast;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Events\Dispatchable;
use Illuminate\Queue\SerializesModels;

class MessageEvent implements ShouldBroadcast
{
    use Dispatchable, InteractsWithSockets, SerializesModels;

    /**
     * Create a new event instance.
     */
    public $message,$username;

    public function __construct($username,$message)
    {
        $this->username = $username;
        $this->message = $message;
    }

    public function broadcastOn()
    {
        \Log::info('Broadcasting on chat channel.');
        return new Channel('chat');
    }




}
```

**Route channel.php**

```
Broadcast::channel('chat', function () {
    return true;
});
```